# syntax editor - how to write dynamic language xml definition file?

Tags: vb.net

So I want to create my own programming language in vb.net 2013 and I see SyntaxEditor by actipro software fits, but how do I write xml definition file that tells which words how to be colored? is there a tutorial somewhere?
Also, how do I make the syntax editor to display the number of the line?
[SCREENSHOOT OF MY PROGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoTFA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the line number is just a property of the SyntaxEditor-control: in WPF-version it is "IsLineNumberMarginVisible". you have to set it to "true". I assume the property in WinForms-version has the same name.

when you install Actipro then there are a lot of samples included. Just look for files named *.langdef and you will find a lot of files where you can see how they shall look like.
There is also a tool "LanguageDesigner.exe" delivered with SyntaxEditor. It gives you a nice UI to create and edit the language file.
Generally I recommend to take a look at the sample projects, specially the SampleBrowser-Project with the "GettingStarted01" to "GettingStarted15" controls.